# C# 2015 int++, ++int, int+=1, int = int +1; issues

Tags: c#, increment

I'm really confused about such a simple problem. The following code wont increment every time.

```
int deviceId = 0;
DeviceCollection coll = DirectSound.GetDevices();
foreach (DeviceInformation dev in coll.Skip(1))
{
    comboBoxDevice.Items.Add(deviceId+": "+dev.Description);
    deviceId++;
    comboBoxDevice.SelectedIndex = 0;
}
```

my Output looks like this:

```
0: speaker1 .....
0: speaker2 .....
1: speaker3 .....
```

can anybody say me why this happend?

I have already tried to solve it like that:

```
++deviceId;
deviceId += 1;
deviceId = deviceId+1;
```

with all of them got the same result.

Comment: Where is `deviceId` defind?

Comment: What output are you expecting instead?

Comment: You won't get that output from a single call to the code you've shown us - you wouldn't see `0` as the `deviceId` twice. My guess is that you're calling this code multiple times. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @OliverLink Perheps you should consider debugging your own code at the first place… Specifically learn to use breakpoints.

Comment: Show `DirectSound.GetDevices()` Is it dependant on `comboBoxDevice.Items` ?

Comment: How about using [MoreLinq's `Index()` extension](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ#index)?

Comment: to WillemVanOnsem in the first line int deviceId = 0;
to JonSkeet i called that funktion excatly 1 time tested with debugging
to OndrejTucny WOOOOW *slow clapping* i know how to use the debugger. if i get threw it step by step it execute devideID++; but the value will not increase.
to CharlesBretana no its not directSound.GetDevices comes from the ref SlimDX and it list me all my output device i just want to add the device names to the combobox that i can select them to playback sounds on the selected device

Comment: @jasen my output should look like:
0: speaker1 .....
>>>1: speaker2 .....
>>>2: speaker3 .....

Comment: Are you going to post an MCVE or not? Voting to close in the current question state.

Answer (score 0):

Problem sloved!

```
        DeviceCollection coll = DirectSound.GetDevices();
        foreach (DeviceInformation dev in coll.Skip(1))
        {
            comboBoxDevice.Items.Add(deviceId +": "+ dev.Description);
            deviceId++;                             
        }
        comboBoxDevice.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

I added the selectedIndexChangedEvent to the ComboBox which will set the deviceId by the selectedIndex of the Combobox. So in the first loop it will set deviceId to 0 again.